# what's wrong with this php code?

Tags: php

Ok, the idea here is to have code that will append SF_ to all key names in an array.
I took my array (which is part of an object), flipped it, added the SF_, and flipped it back.

Somewhere in the process I lost some fields...

here's what I started with:

```
object(stdClass)[12]
  public 'Affiliate_Code__c' => string 'XX-TXUJC3' (length=9)
  public 'AltEmail__c' => string 'benny@oxpublishing.com' (length=22)
  public 'City' => string 'Mobile' (length=6)
  public 'Email' => string 'benny@oxpublishing.com' (length=22)
  public 'Fax__c' => string '251-300-1234' (length=12)
  public 'FirstName' => string 'Benny' (length=5)
  public 'LastName' => string 'Butler' (length=6)
  public 'Phone' => string '251-300-3530' (length=12)
  public 'PostalCode' => string '36606' (length=5)
  public 'State' => string 'AL' (length=2)
  public 'Street' => string '851 E I-65 Service Rd' (length=21)
  public 'test1__c' => float 1
array
  'SF_Affiliate_Code__c' => string 'XX-TXUJC3' (length=9)
  'SF_Email' => string 'benny@oxpublishing.com' (length=22)
  'SF_City' => string 'Mobile' (length=6)
  'SF_Fax__c' => string '251-300-1234' (length=12)
  'SF_FirstName' => string 'Benny' (length=5)
  'SF_LastName' => string 'Butler' (length=6)
  'SF_Phone' => string '251-300-3530' (length=12)
  'SF_PostalCode' => int 36606
  'SF_State' => string 'AL' (length=2)
  'SF_Street' => string '851 E I-65 Service Rd' (length=21)
```

And here's my code:

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->query(($query));



      foreach ($response->records as $SF) {
      }


        var_dump($SF);
        $SF = array_flip($SF);
            foreach ($SF as $key => $value){

                $SF[$key] = 'SF_'.$value;
                }

      $SF = array_flip($SF);
      echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($SF);
        echo "</pre>";
        extract($SF);
```

Any idea?
I'm new to OO programming of any sort, and I'm sure this has something to do with it.
I'm so stupid I have to do:

```
foreach ($response->records as $SF) { }
```

because I don't know how to get to that array any other way.
Help!
Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't the code using $SF in the foreach? Makes no sense... or typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the flip, you end up with duplicate keys - the values become the keys, and your values are not unique (e.g. Email and AltEmail__c both have the same value).

Rather than doing a flip then flipping back, just create a new array and copy the values in with the new keys:

```
$SF_new = array();
foreach($SF as $key => $value ) {
   $SF_new['SF_' . $key] = $value;
}

// And if you want to continue using the $SF name...
$SF = $SF_new;
```

Comment: Well, you all answered correctly, it was hard to choose.  I'm chosing Eric because it's the ost like how I code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`array_flip` will flip the values and keys, as you said. A PHP array cannot have multiple keys with the same name. Try something like this to avoid flipping:

```
<?php
$SF = array();
foreach($response->records as $key => $value)
{
    $SF['SF_' . $key] = $value;
}
```

About the way you get to the array in the object, this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: you mean foreach and not for.

Comment: @easement True, have not been using PHP in a while, did not really think about it. Thanks for your comment, just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$SF = get_object_vars($response);
```

Will transform your object into an array.

Answer (score 0):

flip swaps keys and values.  because you have values that share the same value, you lose them in the flip.